# How to check if a key was pressed in Cosmos c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, operating-system, cosmos

I am creating an operating system using Cosmos C# and how would I check if a key was pressed like A, CTRL, SHIFT, F1, etc. even in graphics mode?

Answer (score 3):

`Console.ReadKey` should work.

Also, you can ask for help in the gitter chat (https://gitter.im/CosmosOS/Cosmos), usually it's faster.